Sumif the total qty by column A


Sheet name is 171,  i want to sumif the total Qty. by gpf_npno
i haven't try. all i can do is the layout in userform. im still figuring out what to do
i try the command button search,
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
 Dim searchValue As String
    Dim foundCell As Range

    ' Get the search query from the textbox
    searchValue = TextBox1.Value

    ' Assuming your data is in Sheet1, Column A
    Set foundCell = Sheets("171").Columns("A:A").Find(What:=searchValue, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

    If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then
        ' Value found, display the address of the cell
        'MsgBox "Found at " '& foundCell.Address
    Else
        ' Value not found
        MsgBox "tang ina mooo. I type mo nang maaayos!"
    End If
End Sub


These three links should help  ... worksheetfunction  ...  worksheetfunction.sumif  ...  SUMIF

Welcome Leo! Read The Tour and earn your first badge!


Assume the textbox named TextBox2 in the second row.
Call worksheet function SumIf to get the total Qty.

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim searchValue As String
    Dim foundCell As Range
    ' Get the search query from the textbox
    searchValue = TextBox1.Value
    ' Assuming your data is in Sheet1, Column A
    Set foundCell = Sheets("171").Columns("A:A").Find(What:=searchValue, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then
        With Sheets("171")
            TextBox2.Value = Application.SumIf(.Columns(1), searchValue, .Columns(4))
        End If
    Else
        ' Value not found
        MsgBox "tang ina mooo. I type mo nang maaayos!"
    End If
End Sub


also i want to add vlookup function in command button, here's my code

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click2()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lookupValue As Variant
Dim result As Variant
' Set the worksheet where your data is located (change "Sheet2" to your actual sheet name)
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SOH")
lookupValue = Me.TextBox1.Value

' Perform the VLOOKUP
On Error Resume Next
result = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookupValue, ws.Range("D:D"), 5, False)
On Error GoTo 0

If Not IsError(result) Then
    Me.TextBox23.Value = result
End If

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click2()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lookupValue As Variant
Dim result As Variant
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SOH")
 lookupValue = Me.TextBox1.Value

On Error Resume Next
result = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookupValue, ws.Range("D:D"), 5, False)
On Error GoTo 0

If Not IsError(result) Then
 
    Me.TextBox23.Value = result
End If

End Sub

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
